# Keep getting syntax error when trying to call python function

Tags: python, function, syntax-error

Can you guys help me out? I've been stuck trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong when calling this function. I have previous examples that, at least to my eyes look exactly the same and work just fine. VSCode claims the syntax error is in the call. I'm sure it's a simple fix but it's driving me mad, Thanks.

```
lst = [4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 25]

def stars(myList):
    for i in range(0, len(myList - 1)):
        print ("*" * (myList[i])
stars(lst)
```

Comment: You get a `SyntaxError` because there is an error in your syntax. In this case, it's your brackets.

Comment: Also `len(myList - 1)` is incorrect, you should use `len(myList) - 1`

Comment: Thanks for the help! Sorry for such a basic question, but it was irritating me. Switching from JS to Python has proved to be a pain with syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in the code.

One is the missing parentheses after **print ("*" * (myList[i])** that will give bellow error

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

So you need to add parentheses as **print ("*" * (myList[i]))**

Second is the wrong condition in range.

**len(myList - 1)** will below error as you cannot subtract from the list directly.

First, you need to get the length by len(myList) then subtract as **len(myList) - 1**

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

Below is the correct code that should work

```
lst = [4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 25]

def stars(myList):
    for i in range(0, len(myList) - 1):
        print ("*" * (myList[i]))
stars(lst)
```

Comment: You should explain what they are instead of just giving them code to copy and paste...

Comment: len(myList - 1) is not the right syntatical way to calculate the length of a list. it should be len(myList)  - 1 as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @Shadow, Yes I was just adding the explanation :)

Comment: Glad to hear :) Also you might want to use backticks (ie, `\``) for the inline code - it's looks nicer than bold (in my opinion anyway)